# Do I need to rebuild the array after putting in a new hot spare?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid5

So my experience with RAID is minimal. So I figured I'd come and ask here. We have a 16 drive RAID system that have 15 drives in RAID 5 with a hot spare left over. Recently one of the drives in the RAID was giving errors so I cloned it over to the hot spare and put a new drive in it's spot. I made the new drive the hot spare as I was told. I was told to rebuild the array after putting in the new drive as a hot spare so I tried and wasn't able to. So my question is do I need to rebuild it and if so why did it tell me I couldn't. Thanks!

UPDATE: So I've come back up to work and looked at the RAID and it pulled in the hot spare into the raid and kicked out another drive.

Comment: What is "it", and *what/how* exactly was "it" telling you what it did? What type of array are you working with (make/model)? In general, a hot-spare disk doesn't activate until a failure occurs. You should not have had to take any action other than inserting a healthy disk when the drive with errors failed.

Comment: It was telling us there was disk errors with slot 9. It's a Falcon 3 from RAIDInc, if I remember correctly. Everything else I was just following directions.

Answer (score 0):

The rebuild is meant to occur when you begin using the existing hot spare in an array, not when you add a new hot spare. After all, it's "spare" and should be unused until needed.

Comment: That's what I figured but it wasn't available at that time and I figured cloning was basicaly "rebuilding" the array with the old hot spare. I could be wrong though.